# How to get the merge type of the returned result of each function in the array parameter?

Tags: typescript

I want the `getInjectData` function to automatically return the merge type of the return value of each inject function based on the `injects` I passed in.

The code is:

```
function getInjectData ({ injects }) {
  cosnt data = {}
  for (let inject of injects) Object.assign(data, inject())
  return data
}

function injectUser () {
  return { user: { name: 'Jack' } }
}

function injectBook () {
  return { book: { author: 'Jack' } }
}

const injectData = getInjectData({ injects: [injectUser, injectBook] })
```

So, I want the type of `injectData` to be:

```
{
  user: {
    name: string
  }

  book: {
    author: string
  }
}
```

Of course, I know that this requirement can be implemented by passing a generic to `getInjectData`:

```
interface InjectData {
  user: {
    name: string
  }

  book: {
    author: string
  }
}
const injectData = getInjectData<InjectData>({ injects: [injectUser, injectBook] })
```

But should there be a way for it to automatically speculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have to help the compiler figure this out.  The variable `data` is inferred to be of type `{}`, which is too wide.  And to represent the intended type of `data` involves some hoop-jumping.

Here's how I'd do it.  First I'd make your function generic like this:

```
function getInjectData<T extends () => object>({ injects }: { injects: T[] }) {}
```

This way the compiler expects that `injects` will be an array of no-arg functions which produce some object type.  Then, `data` should really be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of all those returned object types.

When you examine an array's elements, you will naturally get a union instead of an intersection.  Luckily there's [a way to turn a union into an intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2887218
):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any
  ? (k: U) => void
  : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
  ? I
  : never;
```

Also, when you're done, you might end up with an ugly bundle of intersections like `{a: string} & {b: number} & {c: boolean}` instead of a single type like `{a: string, b: number, c: boolean}`.  You can convert them with another type alias like this:

```
type Prettify<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
```

(this uses conditional type inference and mapped types to walk through the properties and make a single object).

Here's the way I'd declare `data`:

```
function getInjectData<T extends () => object>({ injects }: { injects: T[] }) {
  const data = {} as Prettify<UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<T>>>;
  for (let inject of injects) Object.assign(data, inject());
  return data;
}
```

Just to be clear: `T` is a union of function types which return objects.   `ReturnType<T>` uses a [built in type alias](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1486-L1489) to produce a union of those return types.  `UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<T>>` is the intersection of those return types, and `Prettify<UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<T>>>` is a single object type representing that intersection.  Let's try it out:

```
function injectUser() {
  return { user: { name: "Jack" } };
}

function injectBook() {
  return { book: { author: "Jack" } };
}

const injectData = getInjectData({ injects: [injectUser, injectBook] });
/*
const injectData: {
    user: {
        name: string;
    };
    book: {
        author: string;
    };
}
*/
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-V9AxjgQAhJBIKTh8miZ1iiUxhFVsw7XhvYBBJXprNxXP5wsvYSU6llkhgmIMv7AQHAye8NFBwkrfHAkN4W3j4CV6uk55+ABUIlHwCDC9xrjEcbwl-rYgfieTqag0VwFh+TrEBavUBb1bvR9Hw7Lse1fYB3zgT9fx-YRvWEQ8-CAA)

Comment: Awsome！Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `UnionToIntersection` and `Prettify` are so useful!